# How to save object returned by a web service?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm new to PowerShell and I'm trying to figure out how to save (to a file or database) object returned by the following web service:

```
$apiKey = "00000000-1111-2222-3333-444444444444"
$userName   = "12345678"
$password   = "SamplePassword"

$URI     = "https://www.example.com/api/TestWS.TestService.svc?wsdl" 
$prox = New-WebServiceProxy -uri $URI -namespace WebServiceProxy
$prox.chambersList
$prox.chambersList($userName, $password, $apiKey, 0, $false, 0, $false)

---------------------------------------------------------------------

MemberType          : Method
OverloadDefinitions : {WebServiceProxy.chambersListOutputData, ijfah16c, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null chambersList(string userName, string password, string apiKey, System.Nullable[int] pageNumber, bool pageNumberSpecified, System.Nullable[int] pageSize, bool pageSizeSpecified)}
TypeNameOfValue     : System.Management.Automation.PSMethod
Value               : WebServiceProxy.chambersListOutputData, ijfah16c, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null chambersList(string userName, string password, string apiKey, System.Nullable[int] pageNumber, bool pageNumberSpecified, System.Nullable[int] pageSize, bool pageSizeSpecified)
Name                : chambersList
IsInstance          : True

chambersList                       : {797, 798, 799, 800...}
pagesCount                         : 92
pagesCountSpecified                : True
allElementsCount                   : 918
allElementsCountSpecified          : True
pageNumber                         : 1
pageNumberSpecified                : True
pageSize                           : 10
pageSizeSpecified                  : True
description                        : OK
code                               : OK
codeSpecified                      : True
information                        :
```

I would like to invoke a method called "chambersList" but I'm having trouble understanding how it works. Is it possible to export the returned object (List?, Table?) to a XML / CSV / TXT / database? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the output, I'd gather that you should be able to store the value from the method into a variable, which you can do what you like with in Powershell:

```
$chambersListData = $prox.chambersList($userName, $password, $apiKey, 0, $false, 0, $false)

#Just an example of using the data
if ($chambersListData.allElementsCountSpecified)
{
    $chambersListData.allElementsCount
}

$chambersListData.chambersList | Foreach-Object {

    #do something with the elements
}

$chambersListData.chambersList | Export-Csv "myChambersList.csv"
```

Hard to tell if that last is useful, depends on the contents of chambersList

If this fails, do a `$chambersListData | Get-Member` to see what you can do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands

```
Get-command -verb export
```

And then for each command returned :

```
Help export-....
```

Generally you will pipe you variable to the command:

```
$prox.chambersList($userName, $password, $apiKey, 0, $false, 0, $false) | export-...
```

There are quite few ways to export, csv and **clixml (basically the PowerShell object)** sound like the sort of things you want. **Of course it depends what you want to do afterwards?**

also check more detailed help out here:

```
To see the examples, type: "get-help Export-CSV -examples".
For more information, type: "get-help Export-CSV -detailed".
For technical information, type: "get-help Export-CSV -full".
```

and for export-clixml

```
To see the examples, type: "get-help Export-Clixml -examples".
For more information, type: "get-help Export-Clixml -detailed".
For technical information, type: "get-help Export-Clixml -full".
```